# Calling stored procedure after user inserts data to a table

Tags: mysql, procedure

I need help with calling a stored procedure. Let me explain briefly what the problem is.

I have a "booking" table and whenever new booking is made and new data is inserted into the booking table, I need to call a stored procedure which aims to update field in another table. I have problem with calling the stored procedure after user inserts data into "booking". I don't want to use trigger it needs to be SP. Do you guys think I can use something like AFTER INSERT table_name CALL stored_procedure(). etc

Any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can call a stored proc anytime you want, but I am assuming you want the insert to happen in the same transaction scope as the insert into the booking table(s), so if the booking insert is already a stored proc, just add a call to the new proc inside that proc. Otherwise execute two queries, one for the booking insert one for the new SP

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The data is inserted by user, stored procedure needs to run after user inserts data to booking table.

Comment: if you don't have control over how the "user" calls the initial insert, and therefore cannot add an additional call, then you will have to add a trigger that calls the SP, or if latency is ok, run a batch job periodically that calls the proc and updates the other table

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`. You can put your **store procedure** within the trigger although is not [recommendable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger).

Options you have:

- Call a trigger made by sql code (no store procedures)
- Wrap the INSERT and the CALL to your SP inside a TRANSACTION